# How do I debug using IDE debugger with the Python Prompt Toolkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, prompt-toolkit

I have been using the Python Prompt Toolkit https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit, but Im having a hard time using it with my IDE.

I have to force my IDE to emulate the console as a terminal and it really limits everything I can do with the debugger.

Does anyone have any experience with this and could possibly point me to something that shows the best way to get around this issue?

[image: Configuration options in Pycharm IDE]

Here is the error I receive if I do not emulate the terminal in the console.

[image: Error for not emulating the terminal]